# JXTableHeader resetSortOrder on Shift + click

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxtable

I use JXTable and JXTableHeader to display sortable tables. JXTableHeader supported a way to reset sort order, by holding down shift and left clicking on the headers at the same time. The problem is the following: This reset mode is not possible atm, becuse Java Swing's BasicTableHeaderUI adds a mouse listener to JXTableHeader and eventhough I add my own listener to JXTableHeader, BasicTableHeaderUI's gets triggered and although I reset sort order in my listener's mouseClick method, the BasicTableHeaderUI's immediately sets the same column to be sorted in its own mouseClick method. Problem #2, I cannot use consume on the event, since BasicTableHeaderUI's listener just ignores the flag.

How can I prevent BasicTableHeaderUI's listener to be triggered in a clean way?

Solution:

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437547/sort-jtable-when-mouse-released/14439616#14439616) is the solution I went with. I implemented a wrapper for the BasicTableHeaderUI's MouseListener and changed that to my wrapper on updateUI. My wrapper just ignores the wrapped MouseListener's mouseClick call on a certain condition (-> resetSortOrder).

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532044/jxtable-column-sorting-changes-between-1-0-and-1-6)

Comment: `table.setSortOrderCycle(ASCENDING, DESCENDING, UNSORTED);`

Comment: remove all MouseListener from JTableHeader, all MouseEvent and KeyEvents can be evt.consume(), or redirected, or fireXxxXxxx, for workaround and code search in post by @kleopatra, [a few times answered](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a203657%20[jtable])

Comment: Thanks mKorbel, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437547/sort-jtable-when-mouse-released/14439616#14439616) might actually work, not so nice thou ...

Comment: Thanks Robin and Guillaume, but I really need the original behaviour ...

Comment: beware: such hooking might not work with JXTableHeader because it does some magic - to not sort if in the resizing area - internally (using a private mouseListener) - not sure how/if that one might interfere, never tried :-)